# Seven ate nine: Why is my index 8 being skipped in this d3 selection?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am working on a D3 script that contains a function, drawWorkingLife, which appends 11 images to an SVG. I've noticed the script skips appending the 8th image.

To debug, I can see that if I console.log where I am adding x and y attributes for the image, index 8 is not logged.

In the function drawWorkingLife below, why is index number 8 not logged to the console?

Demo: http://radiocontrolled.github.io/sevenAteNine 
Repo: https://github.com/radiocontrolled/sevenAteNine

```
function drawWorkingLife() {
 var work = svg.selectAll("image")
  .data(workingLife, function(d,i) { 
    return d[i]; 
  })
  .enter()
  .append("g");

  work
  .append("svg:image")
  .attr(opts)
  .attr({
    "x" : function(d,i) {
      console.log(i);
      // why is index 8 skipped? 

    },
    "y" : function(d,i) {
      console.log(i);
      // why is index 8 skipped? 
    },       
    "class" : function(d,i){
      return d;
    }
  })
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .style("opacity", 1);
```

}

Comment: have you tried using a debugger statement instead of console.log()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the code that associates the data with the selection:

```
.data(workingLife, function(d,i) { 
  return d[i]; 
})
```

The second parameter to that call is a function that tells D3 how to uniquely identify each data value. You're returning the `i`th character of the data (which in your examples are all just a string). Your strings are all "workingLife", and the "i" character appears twice in that string. So you've told D3 that data value 4 and data value 8 are the same. D3, therefore, considers the 8th value to be a duplicate.